# active class on menu and parent item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have this HTML code for my menu:

```
<nav id="main-navigation" class="navigation-simple">
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>           
    <li><a class="active-nav" href="">About Us</a>
    <ul>                        
        <li><a class="active-nav" href="about">About</a></li>               
        <li><a href="testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="meet-the-team">Meet The Team</a></li>  
    </ul>
    </li>
</nav>
```

i have added in the `active-nav` class but how can i automatically set the active class on parent and child items when the current URL is the `href` value of the link?

Comment: You can't with just css. You'll either have to use Javascript, or set the `active-nav` inside your server side template (php or something). I would go for that last option to prevent 'blinking' and have an active item for users with js disabled..

Comment: jquery or javascript is fine

Comment: "js active menu based on url" gave me 800k results in Google. Perhaps you should do some research first...

Answer (score 0):

you need java script for this, jQuery is great for beginners!

It could be done like this:

```
var url = window.location.href;
$( "nav li a" ).each(function(index) { 
  if (url.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) >= 0){ 
    $(this).addClass('active-nav');
  }
});
```

line by line -

1. get the current page url
2. for each link in the navigation...
3. check if its href is in the current url
4. if it is, add the class 'active-nav'
5. close if statement
6. close for loop

Comment: You forgot the parent items. And it might break when you have links like `about`, `about-us`, `all-about-our-products`. `about` would be active on all 3 of those pages...

Comment: Yeah, I would advise against putting broken links in the nav. the main 'about' nav link should link to the first page in that section. If you do that, this will work 100%. You are right though, the main 'about' link will be selected on all the sub-pages, but that is how it is expressed in OPs example above.

Comment: True, absolute paths are preferred imo as well, perhaps you should explain that in your answer. You are making assumptions now that may not be true. And about those example links I gave, what if they are all siblings? And there is no href on the OP's parent 'About' link, so I still think you should cover the parent items as well. Good effort though

Comment: how can i add the class to the parent item if the active item is the child item?

Comment: @charlie the above code should select both children and parent, if not... you can use the .parent() selector. $(this).parents('li').addClass('active-nav'); after line 4. Ideally, you should check if the parent actually exists and only apply if necessary, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$(function() {
  $('#main-navigation a').each(function() {
    if(this.href.indexOf(window.location.pathname) === 0) {
      $(this).addClass('active-nav');
    } else {
      // case when something was set to active by the server
      $(this).removeClass('active-nav');
    }
  });
});
```

will do the job.

Make sure you make the if condition safe to your sites deeplinking implementation (e.g. GET params, anchors or multiple domains with same pathname are possible within your navigation).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.filter()` method to find the appropriate link and add the required class:

```
$('#main-navigation li > a').removeClass('active-nav')
.filter(function() {
    return location.href.indexOf(this.href) > -1;
})
.addClass('active-nav') //add class to matched element(s)
//add class to parent(s) of matched, if any
.each(function() {
    $($(this).parents('a'), '#main-navigation').addClass('active-nav');
});
```

Also remember to close your first `ul`.